# Declaring and using variables with select in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure. It does not seem to work. Is there anything that I'm doing wrong?

The error occurs when I declare role on the 4th line.

```
create procedure getRole(in x mediumint unsigned)
begin

DECLARE role INT DEFAULT 3
SELECT user_level INTO role  FROM login_users WHERE user_id = x

        CASE role  
            WHEN 1 THEN  

            WHEN 2 THEN  
                select
                 u.user_level As role,
                 a.id As id,
                 'advisor' As user
                from
                 login_users u
                 inner join login_levels l on u.user_level =l.id
                 inner join rp_adviser a on u.user_id = a.user_id
                where
                 u.user_id = 11;   
            ELSE  
                select
                 u.user_level As role,
                 s.id As id,
                 'student' As user
                from
                 login_users u
                 inner join login_levels l on u.user_level =l.id
                 inner join rp_student s on u.user_id = s.user_id
                where
                 u.user_id = 9;  
                END CASE;  
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This :

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `getRole` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `q1a`.`getRole` (in x mediumint unsigned)
BEGIN

DECLARE role INT DEFAULT 3;
SELECT user_level INTO role  FROM login_users WHERE user_id = x;

if(role = 1 or role = 1)
then
select
                 u.user_level As role,
                 a.id As id,
                 'advisor' As user
                from
                 login_users u
                 inner join login_levels l on u.user_level =l.id
                 inner join rp_adviser a on u.user_id = a.user_id
                where
                 u.user_id = 11;
else
select
                 u.user_level As role,
                 s.id As id,
                 'student' As user
                from
                 login_users u
                 inner join login_levels l on u.user_level =l.id
                 inner join rp_student s on u.user_id = s.user_id
                where
                 u.user_id = 9;
end if;

END $$
```

Comment: It wasnt working in the execute SQL statement, but it worked when I created a new routine.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the declare and use of the variavle `role` in the `CASE` statement in your query is ok but you need to separate the statements in the stored procedure with semicolone `;` like t his:

```
DECLARE role INT DEFAULT 3;
SELECT user_level INTO role  FROM login_users WHERE user_id = x;

    CASE role
    ...
```

Comment: It wasnt working in the execute SQL statement, but it worked when I created a new routine. – asdgfas sagas just now